# Search for duplicates in the same line

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I like what the `uniq` command does, but it looks for duplicates on different lines. I would like to find duplicates even within the same line. what command can do that?

Consider `this  line this this line`, and that I might want to know how many times "this" appears in the same line.

Is there a command that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An other way using `awk`:

```
echo "this  line this this line"| \
awk  'BEGIN{print "count", "lineNum"}{print gsub(/\<this\>/,"") "\t" NR}'

count lineNum
3   1
```

- Which prints count and line number in which `this` word found.
- `gsub()` function's return value is number of substitution made. So we use that to print the number.
- `NR` holds the line number so we use it to print the line number.

Comment: Not quite, `this` will match any substring of a word that is `this`, not whole word e.g. it will match `foothisbar`, `thisspam` and so on. With `gawk`, you can match word boundaries with `\<` and `\>`, so make it as: `gsub(/\<this\>/,"")`

Comment: Accepted and Corrected.

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
grep -Eo '[^[:blank:]]+' file.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

- `grep -Eo '[^[:blank:]]+'` gets the words of the file separated by any whitespace(s)
- `sort` sorts the output
- `uniq -c` gets the cound of words

**Example:**

```
% grep -Eo '[^[:blank:]]+' <<<'this  line this this line' | sort | uniq -c
      2 line
      3 this
```